# Ubuntu 18.04 PXE-booting with Realtek r8152-based NIC, no interface found

Tags: drivers, kernel, realtek, pxe, nic

I am upgrading my PXE boot infrastructure with 18.04, but I am running into a consistent problem with our Dell XPSen - when PXE-booting from the official Dell FM76N (Realtek r8152-based) USB NICs, the laptop picks up iPXE perfectly fine, but upon selecting 18.04.1 (which is set up exactly as I specified 16.04, by extracting the various kernel/initrd files and placing them in a TFTP folder, then setting up an NFS share), the kernel begins to load, but when trying to set up a network interface and mount the NFS folder, it has no NIC available:

```
Begin script casper/premount...
ipconfig: no devices to configure [repeated half a dozen times]
NFS over TCP not available from <server IP>
connect: Network is unreachable
```

The last two messages repeat until I am dropped to a Busybox shell, which proves from both `ip link show` and `ifconfig -a` that there is no network device detected. `dmesg` within that shell shows that the NIC is detected as a USB device but with no indication that it's identified as a network adapter.

I have tried the steps listed here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1843448 to add drivers and firmware to the initrd; I installed the same kernel on a running 18.04 machine, then copied the whole contents of `/lib/modules/4.15.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers` and `/lib/firmware` into the extracted initrd, ran `depmod` and re-zipped it up (creating a file of nearly 200MB versus the standard 37MB initrd!) but no success. When plugged into the working laptop, the USB NIC shows up as expected; `dmesg` identifies it as a network interface and configures it, then Network Manager kicks in and offers it as a usable NIC.

It seems like the Realtek drivers are not being loaded. `dmesg` output from the working machine:

```
[10913.072763] usb 4-1.3: new SuperSpeed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[10913.098583] usb 4-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8153
[10913.098586] usb 4-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=6
[10913.098587] usb 4-1.3: Product: USB 10/100/1000 LAN
[10913.098588] usb 4-1.3: Manufacturer: Realtek
[10913.098589] usb 4-1.3: SerialNumber: 000001000000
[10913.186241] usb 4-1.3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[10913.272127] r8152 4-1.3:1.0 eth0: v1.09.9
[10913.744109] r8152 4-1.3:1.0 enx9cebe85f3e37: renamed from eth0
[10914.316459] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx9cebe85f3e37: link is not ready
[10914.335667] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx9cebe85f3e37: link is not ready
[10928.660784] usb 4-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 7
[10928.661397] r8152 4-1.3:1.0 enx9cebe85f3e37: Stop submitting intr, status -108
```

Whereas during PXE boot, the messages end after the `SerialNumber`. I've also tried `modprobe r8152` which gave no response but exits `1`, and `modinfo r8152`, which curiously tells me `modinfo: can't open '/4.15.0-29-generic/': No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I've figured this out - the necessary `r8152` module is **not** included in the default `linux-modules-4.15.0-29-generic` package, but instead in the `linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-29-generic` package.

Once I installed that, I had to perform the steps in the linked forum thread again - copy all the files into the `kernel/drivers` folder, run `depmod` and then zip up the initrd. Once I copied this to my PXE server, it worked - the link came up and the NFS mount went through. However, now it boots to Emergency Mode, but I've seen [bug reports](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/1754777) for this, so the PXE/NFS bit is working at least.

Now I should try to trim down this 200MB initrd image...