# How to fix initrd issues 'Cannot open root device "ram0"'

Tags: boot, drivers, realtek, pxe

I've installed successfully netboot.xyz and I'm able to install Linux and Windows on multiple devices without any issues.

Recently I got a few Dell Precision laptops with an USB-ethernet adapters and those seem to be having issues with the network adapter.

With a regular netboot Ubuntu 21.04 the Realtek r8153 driver is not loaded so the ISO cannot be retrieved from Ubuntu. I've followed the steps from here: [Ubuntu 18.04 PXE-booting with Realtek r8152-based NIC, no interface found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079240/ubuntu-18-04-pxe-booting-with-realtek-r8152-based-nic-no-interface-found)

```
 find . | cpio --quiet -H newc -o | gzip -9 -n > ../initrd
```

but now initrd is unable to load.

> VFS: Cannot open root device "ram0" or unknown-block(0,0). Please append a correct "root=" boot option

How can I make this work?

Sources:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2468967
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2468782&page=2